# java send wrong data to web service

Tags: java, web-services

Testing a web service, the request soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:syyh="http://syyh.service.webService.ckw.tdh/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <syyh:shfeedXzcxInfo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/Pjx1
c2VybWFya2VyPjxjb25kaXRpb24gdXNlcm5hbWU9IldVZ3dNREF3TkRJPSIgcGFzc3dvcmQ9IlJq
RTNOa2d4TURFMU1qQXhNREF3TURFPSIvPjwvdXNlcm1hcmtlcj4=</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>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</arg1>
      </syyh:shfeedXzcxInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but the data captured by `tcpdump`  looks wrong, the data is actually less than 2000 bytes, but 10000+ bytes captured, the data is too long to paste here, please check it:[here](http://jmp.sh/Un0AVzN)

It seems that the request body was sent repeatedly, but when I change the soap message to a working one, the data captured by tcpdump looks right.

after about 30 seconds, the web service server will return a error says "couldn't parse stream", so I think maybe the server is expecting more data or some kind EOF of the request stream, but making the http request chunked didn't help.

This error originally happened in our java web application which use JAX-WS RI in JDK 1.7.0.45 as web service client.

Can any body help? this error happened on a production server, I am stuck on it for almost one week.

---

I have tested the same message in our test environment, no error at all...and I am sure both production environment and test environment runs the same OS and java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a network layer problem.

The MTU of the client machine is 1500, some device in the network path has a smaller MTU. This cause the packet was dropped, and tcp retransimission happened, that's why the tcpdump get's 10000+ bytes.

after change the MTU to 1400, now it works.

This is something rarely happen, and not specific to java or web service stuff. hope can help others.

Answer (score -1):

The data you're showing is a base64 encoded XML file.  In your link, in request_cause_error.txt, the arg1 field is, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<usermarker>
    <condition username="WUgwMDAwNDI=" password="RjE3NkgxMDE1MjAxMDAwMDE="/>
</usermarker>
```

then the field values here are also base64 encoded.

Obviously I'm not familiar with the protocol but it looks like there is a bunch of re-encoding going on.

Is this not what you expect?

Comment: yes, xml attributes are base64 encoded, then the whole xml are base64 encoded this is intended.